# how to enable driver pdo-sqlsrv in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: php, sql, pdo, yii2, xampp

My error is as follows :

```
Error : PDOException could not find driver
```

When I want to connect to sqlserver with yii2.

i installed xampp.

The database is on an external server.

my PDO drivers contain mysql, pgsql, sqlite but not sqlsrv .

How I can fix it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PHP 8.0 you can change that with your current PHP version number.

Try below solution:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv 
sudo su 
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
exit
sudo phpenmod -v 8.0 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

Here are some detailed guide

[Detail1](https://chukwuemekaigbokwe.medium.com/adding-sqlsrv-extension-on-php-7-x-to-ubuntu-server-2ed6dfa09414)

[Detail2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Note that the ODBC headers are also needed to compile these extensions. On Debian/Ubuntu, the package name is `unixodbc-dev`.